# SDL2 events on mobile

Tags: c++, mobile, sdl, sdl-2, mobile-application

I've fought for a couple of hours with a bug due to a behavior of **SDL2** of which I didn't know anything.
In particular, I didn't know that, on mobile, whenever the user touches the screen, two events are sent:

- The first one was quite obvious to me: **a finger down event**.
- The second one was indeed less obvious: **a mouse button down event**.

The same applies for the finger up/mouse button up events.
Because of them, an internal command was thrown twice giving me an headache.

The target is to support both mobile and desktop environments for reasons that are beyond the purpose of the question.
Also, I can guess **SDL2** works like that in order to support smooth migration of already existent codebase.

Anyway, is there a (let me say) *SDL2-way* to inhibit the mouse related events on mobile?

Honestly, they don't make much sense from my point of view and I would like to get rid of them, unless the software is executed on a desktop environment.
Also, I don't want neither to use compile time parameters nor to have dedicated parts of code the aim of which is to suppress those events on mobile.

The code is quite simple. Below a (maybe) meaningful, reduced example:

```
SDL_Event ev;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev)) {
    switch(event.type) {
    case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
        // read it and throw an internal event E
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        // read it and throw an internal event E
        break;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, both the events above are read when the user touches the screen, as explained.

*** EDIT ***

I didn't mention that I was testing my application on an Android device and I'm far to be sure that the same problem arises on iOS.
See the response below. It seems indeed that the *issue* (that so far I've understood it is not exactly an issue) is mainly due to the way SDL2 treats by default finger events on Android.

Comment: I think we can probably benefit from some more specifics. any code to show?

Comment: Well, I'll try to arrange a meaningful snippet.

Comment: one thing you said perplexes me though - ... `support both mobile and desktop environments for reasons that are beyond the purpose of the question.`   -> you want to support *both* mobile and desktop in the same code?

Comment: I'm using a virtual size, but I'd like to execute that code also on a desktop environment (highly letterboxed, of course) during the development phase. The difference is mainly a matter of those events...

Comment: Can you just use mouse events and ignore finger events on both platforms?

Comment: Unfortunately, finger events have a few more data (you can see their structures), they are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I really like the idea of Christophe to add an event filter, I've found that **SDL2** already [gives support for this problem in terms of an hint](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_ANDROID_SEPARATE_MOUSE_AND_TOUCH?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryDefine%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryHints%29) on Android.

In particular, there exists the hint **SDL_HINT_ANDROID_SEPARATE_MOUSE_AND_TOUCH**.
One can set it by means of the function `SDL_SetHint`. See [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetHint?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryHints%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29%7C%28CategoryDefine%29) for further details.

It's as simple as:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_ANDROID_SEPARATE_MOUSE_AND_TOUCH, "1");
```

As from the documentation of the hint, by default it is set to `0` and that means that:

> mouse events will be handled as touch events and touch will raise fake mouse events

That's true, it was my problem, but by setting it to `1` we can get what follows:

> mouse events will be handled separately from pure touch events

So, no longer fake mouse events on Android devices.

The reason behind the default value is not so clear to me, but this one sounds really like the right way to achieve it.

***EDIT (more details)***

This change seems to be recent.
[Here](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8628&sid=835514338fd163c0f211527783c294b1) is a link to the libsdl forum where they were discussing the issues that arose as a consequence of the patch that introduced this behavior.
Someone had the same problem I had and some others were trying also to explain why the patch had been accepted.

***EDIT: alternative solution***

The hint **SDL_HINT_ANDROID_SEPARATE_MOUSE_AND_TOUCH** is available since **SDL v2.0.4**, so it seems that the only viable solution for lower versions of **SDL2** is to use an event filter.

Anyway, I discourage to query the platform by using `SDL_GetPlatform` in order to decide if to set or not to set an event filter.
Instead, as from the documentation of both [`SDL_MouseMotionEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseMotionEvent) and [`SDL_MouseButtonEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent), there exists the `which` parameter that:

> [...] may be SDL_TOUCH_MOUSEID, for events that were generated by a touch input device, and not a real mouse. You might want to ignore such events, if your application already handles SDL_TouchFingerEvent.

Because of that, I suggest to set an event filter no matter of what's the underlying platform, thus to queue the events or to filter them if needed.

Comment: SDL_TOUCH_MOUSEID is a really nice way to eliminate duplicates. Both Mouse and Touch events can still be handled and the annoying double handling is prevented.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such platform specific deactivation parameter.

The cleanest way to do it would hence be in the initialisation code to query for the platform with SDL_GetPlatform() and, if mobile, set an eventfilter with SDL_SetEventFilter() which prevents the mouse events from being queued.
It's not exactly the answer you expect, but I see no other sdl alternative.

A simpler approach, if you control the code of your event loop, would be to set a flag instead of an event filter, and if the flag is set do nothing on the mouse event. This second approach is however not so clean, as you have to take care of platform specific behaviour in all your code, whereas it's much more isolated in the first alternative.

Comment: Good hint, but I found a SDL2 hint parameter that seems to be meant to solve the problem. Thank you anyway, upvoted for the good suggestion.